# yum: Identifying Packages where Installed version-release is Newer than Repo version-release

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, rpm

I manage my RHEL 6 / 7 systems with **yum** pointed at a local repository that is a replica of the official repository from Red Hat.

Other people have installed newer versions of some packages as follows:

```
rpm -i <package name>-<newer version>-<release number of newer version>.rpm
```

I would rather they'd give me the .rpm because then I could put it in my repo, run **createrepo** to rebuild the repo with the newer package version, and then update the package as follows:

```
yum update <package name>
```

How may I identify installed packages for which the installed package version-release is newer than the version-release in my repo?

Note that this is the opposite of **yum update**, which identifies installed packages for which the installed package version-release is older than the version-release in my repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that other than scripting it there's no easy way.

Scripting implies that
you grab a list of all installed packages via `rpm -qa` then fetch what their latest version is from the repository, using `repoquery`. And compare whether the latter versions are older than the former ones.

To speed this up a bit, you may act upon only packages that appear to be installed other than from repos. So as opposed to comparing versions for all pkgs from `rpm -qa`, you will use a  list from:

```
yum list installed | grep @/
```

... which will get the list of packages installed via `yum install /path/to/some.rpm`

and:

```
yum list installed | grep installed
```

... will get the list of packages installed via `rpm -i /path/to/rpm`